# How to best utilize TextToSpeech usage in Kotlin Android app that has multiple activities using TextToSpeech

Tags: android, kotlin, text-to-speech

I am writing an app that is making use of TextToSpeech in 4 different activities in the app.  My question is... what is the best way to utilize TextToSpeech across the app's domain?

I currently have the TextToSpeech being defined and started up in each activity and that looks to be causing much unnecessary overhead.  And that is probably not the right way to efficiently use TextToSpeech.  I am thinking that I should have just one instance of TextToSpeech and have that resource shared by the various activities.

Should the TextToService functionality be placed in a Singleton? Or in a service?  Any insight on what is considered a best practice is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This is probably an "opinion" question, but I'm quite sure that TextToSpeech object is designed to be used separately where needed as the actual engine that it relies on already runs as a service (TextToSpeechService) in the background.  I don't know what the memory use comparison would be vs using a singleton but probably not worth it IMO.

Comment: @Nerdy Bunz - yes an opinion question and yours was quite helpful as I did not know that the engine ran in the background as a service.  Mission accomplished,  Thank you!